# php mysql associative array for graph report

Tags: php, mysql, graph

i need the output like below.i want to generate a graph for my report so i need the result in mysql_fetch_assoc. i am new to this concept. basically am doing mysql_fetch_array thats all but now i need the associative array function.

```
$date = array("date" => reading);

$data = array("28-Sep-2012" => .0032, "27-Sep-2012" => .0028, "29-Sep-2012" => .0021,
"24-Sep-2012" => .0033);
```

Comment: here below my query:

    $results = mysql_query("SELECT vaccum_value,date FROM vaccum_details where serial_number='10P1005'");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
     // i don't know what would be here?
    }

Comment: You can regenerate a new array to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
$results = mysql_query("SELECT vaccum_value,date FROM vaccum_details where serial_number='10P1005'");
$data=array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results))
{ 
    $data[$row['date']]=$row['vaccum_value'];
}

print_r($data);
```

Comment: @SureshbalajiGunasekaran: This is the simple PHP array functionality. create an array with date as key and vaccum_value as a array value.

Comment: but i need the output like this array("28-Sep-2012" => .0032, "27-Sep-2012" => .0028, "29-Sep-2012" => .0021,
"24-Sep-2012" => .0033);  instead of [] square bracket i need "" boss... after i run the script with ur code i got a output like this Array ( [28-Sep-2012] => 31.6 [04-Oct-2012] => 0.99 [03-Oct-2012] => -3 );

Comment: both are same.. the key of the array is string only.